# Validate VBA drop down on click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down select list in a VBA form I would like to validate as soon the user clicks on it. It needs to check that a pre-requisite drop down has been filled already.

This is to avoid the user jumping ahead on the form because there are certain fields that need to be filled out first. My attempt so far is not working:

```
Private Sub cbo_moduleName_Click()

    If Len(cbo_moduleCode.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a module code")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `cbo_moduleCode` on your `UserForm`? What error message you getting? Can you provide a screenshot of your `UserFrom`?

Comment: Oops my bad. I had posted an answer for you but then realized I was using VB6, not VBA.

Comment: @Boann your answer is correct, in vba the only diff is the event is named  `cbo_moduleName_Enter` not `cbo_moduleName_GotFocus()`

Comment: @brettdj cbo_moduleCode is a dropdown menu in my form. Here is a picture http://i46.tinypic.com/okwwut.png

Comment: @AlexK Er I'll undelete it then, but Excel is crashing when I try it so I dunnoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `Click` event is activated only when the box's value is changed with the mouse, not every time it is physically clicked on. Try this:

```
Private Sub cbo_moduleName_Enter()

    If Len(cbo_moduleCode.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a module code")
        cbo_moduleCode.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Works fantasically. Thank you very much!